# How to create C# .Net tests dinamically from scenario files

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, tfsbuild

Currently we have one `TestMetod` that works on 200+ scenario files. The `TestMetod` take all the files from pre-defined folder, and iterate over them.

Currently, in the test explorer in Visual Studio, and in TFS Build results, it appear as one test: If all of the scenarios are ok - that test passes; if some of them don't work as expected - that test fails.

We want to seperate it to 200+ "test cases" both in VS and in the build results. But - we also want the ability to add and remove scenarios without touching the code, so `DataTestMethod`/`DataRow` don't work for us.

Is there way to do it?

Comment: If your test depends on the file system, then it's not a unit test; it's an integration test.

Comment: @KennethK. OK. I edited out the tag. However, we still run this test and want to separate it to multiple "test cases".

Comment: @Y. Shoham, I know that you have 200+ scenario files, but one test method just has one result if you run it unless you run it for 200 times. Another issue is that whether you could control the execute order for 200 scenario files, for example, you could change parameter and just run the 199th scenario file. If you can, you could create the bat file and run the same test method for 200 times using the command line, so it will have 200 results. Of course, the precondition is that you could control the order for 200+ scenario files, and not run all 200+ scenario for 200 times.